# Read new field from query with EF

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have a dbset in dbcontext:

```
public DbSet<Table> Table { get; set; }
```

of class

```
public class Table
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

I also have a raw query with new field got from other query `(SELECT ...)`

```
"SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT ...) AS QueryField FROM Table"
```

How to make new object with `QueryField` via EF?

If I use this

```
var items = _context.Table
                .FromSqlRaw(
                    "SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT ...) AS QueryField FROM Table"
                ).ToList();
```

I got the error "Invalid column name 'Address'"

If I use this

```
            var items = _context.Table
                .FromSqlRaw(
                    "SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT ...) AS QueryField FROM Table"
                ).Select(x => new
                {
                    x.Id,
                    x.Name,
                }).ToList();
```

I can not read `QueryField` because `x` has `Table` type and there is no such property/filed there.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share your `(SELECT ...)` but it could look more or less like this:

```
var items = _context.Table
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    x.Id,
                    x.Name,
                    QueryField = _context.OtherTable.Select(...)
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: `(SELECT ... )` is complicated query and looks like `SELECT TOP (1) (SELECT LinkName FROM Table3 AS Table4
            INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table4.Field2 = Table2.Id
            WHERE (Table4.Field1 = Table.Id) FOR XML PATH('')) AS Field3 FROM Table3 AS Table5`. But I think it does not matter. `QueryField = _context.OtherTable.Select(...)` is not useful because I do not have DbSet `OtherTable` in my DbContext.

Comment: You cannot do that with `FromSqlRaw`

Comment: Ok, and what the right method to resolve my task, if I go to completely wrong direction? In general I need to convert a query to the class instance.